# How to record a view's activity in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to record a view i.e what ever activity is going on the view i want to record it and save it as an .mp4 . I have some how managed to record the view and saved the recorded video as .mp4 to the Camera Roll as well.I can see the animation on the real device when I run the project.

But what happening is the animation that is happening on the imageView is not getting record i.e I am basically animating a set of images on the ImageView i.e a sub view of the view (ContentView) that I want to record.

For recording the view I am using [IAScreenCaptureView](https://github.com/adam-roth/screen-cap-view) library. And the code that I am doing is as follow :

```
@IBOutlet var contentView: IAScreenCaptureView!
@IBOutlet var mainImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var animateImageView: UIImageView!

 let myimgArr = ["beauty_01","beauty_02","beauty_03","beauty_04","beauty_05","beauty_06","beauty_07","beauty_08","beauty_09","beauty_10","beauty_11","beauty_12","beauty_13","beauty_14","beauty_15","beauty_16","beauty_17","beauty_18","beauty_19","beauty_20","beauty_21","beauty_22","beauty_23","beauty_24","beauty_25","beauty_26","beauty_27","beauty_28","beauty_29","beauty_30"]

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        animate_images()

    }

 func animate_images()

    {
        var images = [UIImage]()

        for i in 0..<myimgArr.count
        {
            images.append(UIImage(named: myimgArr[i])!)
        }

        animateImageView.animationImages = images
        animateImageView.animationDuration = 2.0
        animateImageView.startAnimating()
        contentView.addSubview(animateImageView)

    }

var t = false
    @IBAction func doneButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if t {

            print("Stopped")
            contentView.stopRecording()

        }else {

            print("Started")
            contentView.startRecording()
        }

        t = !t

    }
```

Hope I am able to convey my self. Thanks in advance any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want this, but... are you trying to make an AppPreview? Are you trying to manually run your app and record it?

Comment: @dfd : yeah! Its just I want what ever is going on the View i.e the ContentView here in my case I want to record it and save to the camera roll.Basically I am having some animations like Falling snow , Rain Drops and Blinking animations I want them to get recorded. Hope I am able to explain my self.

Comment: You are. I don't think this will work for you, but I use QuickTime to record things I do manually, including AppPreviews. (It gives me a "clean" status bar.) You can record a *.mov* and then use QT or iMovie (or whatever may be available) to convert to *.mp4* and then AirPlay to drop it into a device's camera roll. I know this is manual so I'm pretty sure it won't help you. But maybe it's a start... maybe after getting the *.mp4* you can add it to the asset catalog. Good luck!

Comment: @dfd  Thank you for your valuable comment i'll try the same what you said and i'll update later.